# Windows could not start the Windows Firewall on Local Computer

Tags: windows-7, services, windows-firewall, credentials

I've been unable to start my **Windows Firewall service** for a while now.  How can I get it to start?

When I try through the Services manager (services.msc) I get this error:

[image]

I am running `services.msc` as administrator.

The `Event Viewer` show this error message:

> The Windows Firewall service terminated with service-specific error Access is denied..

The current logon credentials are:

[image]

I've tried `Local system account` and get the following error:

[image]

I have run the `System File checker tool` (SFC.exe) but found no problems.

> Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

I got an error trying to run the `FixIt` on the following page:

http://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_firewall_diagnostic/en-us

Which claims to do this:

> What it fixes...
>
> - Windows Firewall is not the default firewall
> - Windows Firewall does not start
> - Windows could not start Windows Firewall. Service-specific error 5 (0x5)
> - Remote Assistance is not working because it is blocked by Windows Firewall
> - You cannot access shared files and printers because sharing is blocked by Windows Firewall
> - BFE service is missing
> - Firewall will not start Error Code 80070424

The error I got was:

[image]

I have even reset the security on the service to what it should be after building the OS by following these instructions:

> **Part 1: Creating the policy template.**
>
> 1. Open a command prompt.
> 2. Run mmc.exe.
> 3. File menu > Add/remove snap-in > Security Templates > Add button > OK button.
> 4. Right-click on the Security Templates > New Template Search Path > Select C:\Windows\Security\Templates as the destination.
> 5. Right-click the C:\Windows\Security\Templates directory > New Template > specify the name as Server 2008 Firewall > OK button.
> 6. Expand the Server 2008 Firewall node > click on the System Services node.
> 7. Right-click the Windows Firewall service > Properties.
> 8. Put a check in the "Define this policy" checkbox.
> 9. Select the Automatic radio button.
> 10. Select the Edit Security button.
> 11. Ensure the following entries are listed. If they aren't, then add them:
>
>     - SYSTEM: Full Control
>     - Administrators: Full Control
>     - INTERACTIVE: Read
> 12. Click OK, and OK again to close the Windows Firewall Properties dialog window.
> 13. Right-click on the Server 2008 Firewall node again on the left-hand side, and choose Save.
>
> **Part 2: Applying the template security.**
>
> 1. In the same mmc, select the File manu > Add/remove snap-in > Security and Configuration Analysis > Add button > OK button.
> 2. Right-click the Security Configuration Node > Open Databse (think of this as Create Database).
> 3. Specify a database name > Open button.
> 4. In the Template window, open the C:\Windows\Security\Templates\Server 2008 Firewall.inf.
> 5. Right-click on the Security Configuration node > Configure Computer Now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as no-one has (can?) answer this - I'll post what I did to work around the issue.

Restored to an image I took just over a year ago.  Problem solved, kinda.

Answer (score 3):

This may be caused because the “NT Service\MpsSvc” account does not have adequate permissions on the following registry key:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess`

Detailed solution:

- Browse to the key in Registry Editor (as administrator).
- Right click **SharedAccess**, and click **Permissions**.
- Click **Add**.
- In the “Enter the object names to select” field,
  type `NT SERVICE\mpssvc` (case-insensitive).
- Then click **Check Names**. The name should change to `MpsSvc`.
- Click OK.
- Select “Full Control” in the “Allow” column.
- Click OK.

I encountered this problem on Server 2012 R2 today,
and got the above fix from a [thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/the-windows-firewall-service-terminated-with/8f6e7846-e647-4673-ae26-fd4c38860df1) on Microsoft Community. It worked like a charm for me.