# How to properly diagnose Windows 10 pro firewall not functioning

Tags: windows, firewall, windows-firewall, windows-defender

Ok, macOS / Linux native here on Windows territory and a bit lost.

I'm helping a family friend upgrade to Windows 10. He has a **company laptop** that he was allowed to keep after his retirement. It had Windows 7 Pro on it. I upgraded it via Microsofts own Upgrade application and it worked great. All files/folders still in place and all applications working smoothly, except for the Windows (Defender) Firewall:

- When I look at the firewall setting in the renewed settings menu it is set to "off" and the button is greyed out.
- In the configuration screen -> firewall settings there is an exclamation mark with a warning message that the firewall isn't set to it's default settings. There is also a button to restore the default setting but pressing it throws an errorcode 0x80070437

[image]

- Within the Windows 10 settings app there is also a firewall status screen that shows:

[image]

- I tried logging into the administrator account to press the same button but same error persists.
- I downloaded & ran the "Windows Firewall Troubleshooter" program but it also failed to solve the problems. In the detailed report it read:

> "Windows could not start the Windows Firewall on Local Computer"

- I tried running services.msc and starting the Windows Defender Firewall service from there but it keeps shutting itself down directly after it starts.
- Finally I tried restting the service via CommandPrompt (run as Administrator) using the command `Netsh advfirewall reset` but it returns:

[image]

**EDIT 1**

By advice of @harrymc I also tried the solution offered [here](https://superuser.com/a/1027856/8672) which boils down to giving the “NT Service\MpsSvc” account adequate permissions, but the errors still persist..

---

**I am left without a clue as to what I can do to further diagnose the problem?**

Comment: Check the procedure in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1027856/8672) and if the described permission is there, if not add it. If this is still not enough, do it also for registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dhcp`.

Comment: @harrymc Thnx, will do! Will report back findings.

Comment: @harrymc - Unfortunately it did not work, I edited my Question to include this failed attempt as well as adding in some screenshots.

Comment: Have a look at [this article](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/70749-restore-default-windows-defender-firewall-settings-windows-10-a.html) for resetting Windows Defender settings to the default.

Comment: @harrymc - Yes, I saw that article before, I believe I tried all methods. I am sure of the first 3, all failed. I am doubting now about the 4th, the powershell attempt. Will retry that during my next attempt and report back.